# How to retrieve index number from a 'for' loop of a dict in Django Views

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-views

I am trying to get the index number of `{% for p in mydict_1 %}` so that I can use that index on another dict to get the value. I want to use `p` as an index number. How to do this within Django Views?
Data from both lists corresponds to the index in a series.

```
mylist_1 = [{'itemCode': 'AZ001', 'price': 15.52}, {'itemCode': 'AB01', 'price': 31.2}, {'itemCode': 'AP01', 'price': 1.2}] #list of dict
mylist_2 = [{'prop': 'val000'}, {'prop': 'val008'}, {'prop': 'val009'}] #list of dict

{% for p in mylist_1 %}
    <tr>
       <td><a>{{p.itemCode}}</a></td>
       <td><a>{{p.price}}</a></td>
       #Want to use p's index number to get value of that index from mylist_2
       <td><a>{{mylist_2.[p].prop}}</a></td> #How to do this correctly? Expecting val000 for index 0
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't. Django's template language deliberately restricts that to prevent people writing *business* logic in the template. You can pass the dictionaries with [**`zip(…)`** [python-doc]](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip) to the template:

```
def my_view(request):
    # …
    context = {
        # …,
        'mydicts': zip(mydict_1, mydict_2)
    }
    return render(request, 'some-template.html', context)
```

in the template you then iterate with:

```
{% for p, q in mydicts %}
    {{ p.itemCode }}
    {{ p.price }}
    {{ q.prop }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: My example had errors, I fixed them. Is there a way to get the index number for p in `{% for p in mylist_1 %}`?

Comment: @KapishM: the index numbers yes, with `{{ forloop.counter0 }}`, but you can not *subscript*, so even if you somehow have the index, you can not access the i-th element of `mylist_2`, (except for inefficient nested loops).

Comment: Thanks for the help. I can modify and put both lists in one list; in that case, can I used the idex number on the parent list?

Comment: @KapishM: no, you can *not* subscript. So basically `x[y]` is impossible if `y` is a variable (except if you would use nested loops, but that would be horribly inefficient). That is done *on purpose*, exactly to prevent people from doing all such things in a *template*. The *view* simply needs to "prepare" data such that it is easy for the template to render it.

Comment: Thank you again for your help. I was able to solve the problem using filters.